# What are some words that are more all-encompassing than universe?

Tags: word-request

I thought universe was all encompassing, but then I thought about multiverses, and then I thought about parallel universes, so what's a word that's more all-encompassing than an universe, and what's the ultimate word that encompasses all things?

For example:

> The ____ contains all universes including parallel and those from
>   other dimensions.

Comment: "mother universe" (my coinage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[The universe](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/214800)" already covers absolutely everything.

> All existing matter, space, time, energy, etc., regarded collectively, esp. as constituting a systematic or ordered whole; the whole of creation, the cosmos.

Everything else you're talking about doesn't actually exist. Sci-fi writers can come up with anything they'd care to. "[The multiverse](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123653)" is pretty standard.

> orig. *Science Fiction.* A hypothetical space or realm of being consisting of a number of universes, of which our own universe is only one; (*Physics*) the large collection of universes in the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, according to which every event at the quantum level gives rise to a number of parallel universes in which each in turn of the different possible outcomes occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, [the Wikipedia entry on Multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse) suggests that it also covers parallel universes. So, it would seem *multiverse* is actually the word you're looking for.

*Omniverse* might work even better, since the prefix *omni-* implies *all-encompassing* (whereas *multi-* only hints at a collection of universes, of which there could be many, depending on the context).

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to @Ily's opinion, I'd agree with the second sense in the OED link they supply.  "Multiverse" is not a science-fiction term, but a perfectly reasonable one used within the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics.

But, to continue that theme, there's another term proposed by a credible physicist, although it is extremely speculative -- but definitely a serious, non-fictional proposition:

[The Ultimate Ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis) is proposed by Max Tegmark to refer to the collection of absolutely all self-consistent logical structures, going far beyond the concept of physical existence that "universe" or "multiverse" refer to, and instead encompassing anything that might exist in mathematics, logic and computer science.